# Correlation analysis between 2 datasets using R or python

Tags: python, r, dataframe

Dataset 1

```
ID Protein1 Protein2 Protein3    
1    
2    
3    
...
```

Dataset 2

```
ID RNA1 RNA2 RNA3    
1    
2    
3
...
```

How do I write a script that can look at the correlation between each pairwise of protein columns in dataset1 and RNA columns in dataset2 matched by ID?

What I want for output is like:

```
Interaction            Correlation Coefficient    
Pritein1-RNA1     
Protein1-RNA2    
Protein1-RNA3    
Protein2-RNA1    
Protein2-RNA2    
.......
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi XXWANGL. You can keep code/table whitespace/formatting by indenting each line with 4 spaces (or highlight the block of text and click the `{}` button in the editor). I took care of it for your question (please feel to correct anything if I made a mistake).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can actually combine them into one dataframe and use `df.corr()`

Comment: Give the shape of each dataframe